# Spring Boot Reactive: adding @Validate annotation to controller causes associated test to fail

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm currently working in a Sprig Boot(2) reactive project. All CRUD endpoints and tests were working just fine. Then I deiced to add validations when creating a todo, for this purpose I added annotations to my repository class:

```
@Data
@Container(containerName = "myContainer")
public class ToDo {
    @Id
    @PartitionKey
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Category must not be blank")
    private String category;
    @NotNull(message = "Complete must not be null")
    @AssertTrue(message = "Complete must be either true or false")
    private boolean complete;
    @NotBlank(message = "Name must not be blank")
    private String name;

}
```

And I added a @Valid annotation to the controller method for creating a todo

```
@PostMapping
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<ToDo>> createTodo(@Valid @RequestBody ToDo toDoItem) {
        return toDoService.saveItem(toDoItem)
                .flatMap(savedItem -> Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedItem)))
                .onErrorResume(DuplicateItemException.class, ex ->
                        Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ToDoDAO())));
    }
```

This is the corresponding test:

```
@Test
void createItem() {
        ToDoDAO newItem = new ToDoDAO();
        newItem.setName("New Item");
        newItem.setCategory("Category");
        newItem.setComplete(false);

        createItem(newItem).expectStatus().isCreated();
    }
```

The problem: by adding the @Valid annotation this particular test fails to pass returning a bad request response. If I remove the @Valid annotation the test pass again. Any suggestions is truly appreciate it.

I'm expecting a returning status code of 201, created.

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting when `@Valid` annotation is added by looking into the logs?

Comment: I think it might be an issue with `@AssertTrue` annotation on top of `complete` property in your `ToDo` class. As you are passing `false`, I believe `@AssertTrue` will always expect `true`. So, try passing `true` and run the test

Comment: Probably data issue, check test data seems like Valid is trying to validate something but fails to validate!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the @Valid annotation. What I did to solve the problem was to remove the annotation and create a helper class and use it in the service implementation class. This approach is better for performance because validates the item before hitting the database:

```
@Override
public Mono<ToDoDAO> saveItem(ToDoDAO toDoItem) {
    todoValidator.validate(toDoItem);

    return todoRepository.getItem(toDoItem.getId())
            .flatMap(existingItem -> Mono.<ToDoDAO>error(new DuplicateItemException("Id " + toDoItem.getId() + " already exists in the database")))
            .switchIfEmpty(todoRepository.save(toDoItem));
}
```